# How to make this for Safari?

Tags: css, safari

[The Problem](https://codepen.io/lagudal/pen/WNRWNVw) -

I want to wrap menu items in 2 lines, second line must begin after first word.
With white-space: normal, word-spacing for first-line pseudo-element and width css properties  work its fine in Chrome, Firefox, but not working in Safari.

Why is this css not working in Safari?

```
.menu {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 30px auto;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu-item {
  width:  calc(100% / 5);
   white-space: normal;
}
.menu-item:first-line {
  word-spacing: 200px;
  color: red;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does it look like in Safari? What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: I'd suggest you to  just wrap the first word of each link in its own span tag with display: block applied, or to use a <br />

Comment: Safari Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.4)

Comment: [quote]I'd suggest you to just wrap the first word of each link in its own span tag with display: block applied, or to use a <br /> – Fabrizio Calderan[/quote]
this code is or example, i can it not jast as html edit.